# How to test automatically a generated bar code within a PDF Form without a physical scanner?

Tags: java, unit-testing, image-processing, pdf-generation, barcode

We have a java application which generates PDF forms which have at the footer 2 dimensional bar codes. The bar codes contain the companies form id and the customer id.

Now we are looking for a way to test the generated PDF automatically without a physical scanner. Means we just like to read the PDF via Java API, render & capture somehow internally the bar codes and read their content. So this is the rough idea.

The question if this approach is achievable? Does anybody know some APIs in Java which may able to do such a thing? e.g.

1. reading a PDF and rendering its content as an image in the background?
2. reading a bar code image and extracts its conent?
3. processing an image and extract text content (OCR)?

Comment: Given most phones can be barcode scanners simply by taking a picture of the barcode, there's probably some standard libraries available that'll do the image->barcode data stuff. no idea what/where they'd be, though.

Comment: This is true I found some image processing library at http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Comment: I found also some free image OCR processing library, but no idea if this is a good one http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/

Comment: And I also found a free library, example how to convert a PDF as an image  http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/pdfbox/PDFToImage.java.html The question is also here if this is a good one or if there exists better free libraries? Any experience with these?

Comment: if you're not Amazon you could create BarCodes per customer static and insert always the same -checked- image. Are you Amazon?